# (ILC0005 Error) i couldn't compile UWP x64/x86 Release project

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, compiler-errors, uwp

I'm creating a UWP Project for windows 10.

I have googled about this problem, cleaned obj and bin folder by myself.

Then, my project folder, there is only ascii characters.

My changes had no effect.

> 1>C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.NetNative\x64\ilc\IlcInternals.targets(1192,5):
>   error : 内部コンパイラ エラー (Internal Compile Error)
>   1>C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.NetNative\x64\ilc\IlcInternals.targets(1192,5):
>   error : ILT0005: 'C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.NetNative\x64\ilc\Tools\nutc_driver.exe
>   @"(Project
>   Folder)obj\x64\Release\ilc\intermediate\MDIL\ECToolControl.rsp"'
>   は終了コード 1 を戻しました (was returned exit code 1)

Comment: Have you check `Compile with .Net Native tool chain` option in project property ?

Comment: Thanks, i unchecked that option, then compiled successfully. what a relief!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.NetNative\x64\ilc\IlcInternals.targets(1192,5): error : 内部コンパイラ エラー (Internal Compile Error) 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.NetNative\x64\ilc\IlcInternals.targets(1192,5): error : ILT0005: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.NetNative\x64\ilc\Tools\nutc_driver.exe @"(Project Folder)obj\x64\Release\ilc\intermediate\MDIL\ECToolControl.rsp"' は終了コード 1 を戻しました (was returned exit code 1)

Please try to uncheck `Compile with .Net Native tool chain option` in project property. It will work.

Comment: Yeah, but then it isn't compiled with the .NET Native tool chain resulting in slower performance. It builds, but like so many other workarounds, it is not a solution.